# Using two tables as input for multi-output regression with keras, the missing matrix product

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

In the keras MWE below I'm trying to train a multi-output regression model with 1000 samples having 20 features (X) as input and producing outputs of size 50 (Y). However, I'm missing a step that I fail to wrap my head around and that I miss the word to describe properly. Let me try anyway, and please forgive the mess:

Here, each one of the 50 outputs is characterised by a set of 10 "feature filters" which are here to interact (through e.g. a dot product) with the 20 features to produce the numeric output. I miss a layer that would train a unique weight matrix of size (20, 10) whose sum (or average) subsequently produces the numeric output Y. The idea is that the output reacts to the features in ways that are dictated by those feature filters and that those interactions are consistent across outputs (e.g. high values in one feature filter might lead to a higher reaction to one feature and lower to another one, and those positive/negative relationships are not output-specific but identified for the whole dataset via the common weight matrix of size 10x20).

How could that side-input matrix (10, 50) of output-specific "feature filters" enter the network? My try below consists in (1) a tensordot product for every sample with the side-matrix (i.e. 3D output), which is (2) subsequently flatten to 1D to interact with a small Dense layer. The dense layer is then (3) tiled/repeated so that it stays small and learn weights that apply to all outputs. The tiled dense output is then (4) dimensionally reduced through averaging to fit the output format of (n, 50).

The problem with this approach is the Dense layer is fully connected, when all that is needed is a locally connected weight matrix (10 * 20) that is tiled 50 times. That is, 1 weight/bias per interaction between feature and feature filter, which apply to every outputs. Having that one weight per interaction we can then visualise which interaction are key to match the output (which is not possible if fully connected).

I suspect I need to replace the dense layer by some locally connected or convolutional or separable or some sort of layer that I don't really understand. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

## create dummy input/output matrices
XData = np.ones((1000, 20)) ## 1000 samples, 20 features
YData = np.ones((1000, 50)) ## 1000 samples, 50 outputs
filterData = np.ones((10, 50)) ## 10 feature filters, 50 outputs
filterData = tf.cast(filterData, tf.float32) ## needed for tf.math.reduce_mean() below

## input of size (n, 20)
input = keras.Input(XData.shape[1])
## dot product with filterData, out size = (n, 20, 10, 50)
tdot = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.tensordot(x, filterData, axes=0))(input)
# flatten for dense layers, out size = (n, 10000)
tflat = keras.layers.Flatten()(tdot)
## learning dense layer, out size = (n, 20*10),
tdense = keras.layers.Dense(XData.shape[1] * filterData.shape[0], activation="linear")(tflat)
## tiling layer that repeats the dense layer for every output
ttile = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.repeat(x, filterData.shape[1]))(tdense)
## reduce dimensions through averaging to fit YData, out size = (n, 50)
tmean = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.reduce_mean(x, axis=(2)))(ttile)
## make the model
model = keras.Model(input, tmean)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mse'
)

history = model.fit(
    x = XData,
    y = YData,
    epochs = 3,
    validation_split = 0.3,
    verbose = 2,
    batch_size=10
  )
```

**EDIT**

The code below achieves the singular connection, i.e. one weigth per feature/feature_filter interaction (shared throughout outputs), that the dense layer does not allow. It consists in a collection of 20 * 10 = 200 single unit dense layer that are subsequently concatenated, before being tiled 50 times. However learning is very poor and maybe setting that concatenated colection inside a time distributed layer, as suggested by @SoheilStar could help. However the presence of the loop prevents me from using it in the sequential API code given by @SoheilStar. Any help on this?

```
## create dummy input/output matrices
XData = np.ones((1000, 20)) ## 1000 samples, 20 features
YData = np.zeros((1000, 50)) ## 1000 samples, 50 outputs
filterData = np.ones((10, 50)) ## 10 feature filters, 50 outputs
filterData = tf.cast(filterData, tf.float32) ## needed for tf.math.reduce_mean() below

## input of size (n, 20)
input = keras.Input(XData.shape[1])

## dot product with filterData, out size = (n, 20, 10, 50)
tdot = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.tensordot(x, filterData, axes=0))(input)

# flatten for dense layers, out size = (n, 10000)
tflat = keras.layers.Flatten()(tdot)

## singular connection layer, i.e. a concatenated collection of single unit dense layer, out size = (n, 200)
dense_list = [None] * (filterData.shape[0] * XData.shape[1])
for i in range(filterData.shape[0] * XData.shape[1]):
    dense_list[i] = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(tflat[:,i:(i+1)])
tdense = keras.layers.Concatenate()(dense_list)

## tiling layer that repeats the dense layer for every output
ttile = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.repeat(x, filterData.shape[1]))(tdense)

## reduce dimensions through averaging to fit YData, out size = (n, 50)
tmean = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.reduce_mean(x, axis=(2)))(ttile)

## make the model
model = keras.Model(input, tmean)
```

**EDIT 2**

To address the previous problem of having the for loop in the time distributed layer, I defined a custom function to give to the time distributed layer:

```
## define a custom layer to be used in a time distributed layer with the sequential api
class customLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_dim = filterData.shape[0] * XData.shape[1]
        self.dense_list = [None] * (self.input_dim)
        for i in range(self.input_dim):
            self.dense_list[i] = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")
        self.concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()
        self.flat = keras.layers.Flatten()

    def call(self, inputs):
        flat_input = self.flat(inputs)
        list = [None] * (self.input_dim)
        for i in range(self.input_dim):
            list[i] = self.dense_list[i](flat_input[:, i:(i+1)])
        return self.concat(list)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_dim):
        return (None, self.input_dim)

## transpose and time distribute along the first dimension (now the output size)
tdot_ = tf.transpose(tdot, [0, 3, 1, 2])

## call the customLayer inside a time distributed layer
tcustom = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(customLayer())(tdot_)
```

And this work, technically, but learning is very poor. The proposition of @SoheilStar below, works after changing the last line so that we have instead:

```
## This layer would try to train its parameters according to each parameter
tdense_ = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())(tdot_)
tdense_ = [tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))(tdense_[:, :, i][..., None]) for i in range(XData.shape[1] * filterData.shape[0])]
tdense_ = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(tdense_)
```

Although again learning is poor, but it is probably to be expected with my real data and the small number of weights in presence.

Comment: I think your writing is not clear to understand the whole picture. Can you make it easier to understand?

Comment: Thanks @M.Innat, I have edited the text (sorry it is still verry verbose but I can't simplify much more) and updated the code which I hope should help getting the idea! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

I am not sure if I got the problem correctly. If you are looking to train the Dense layer simultaneously on the 50 outputs, then you can use `TimeDistributed` layer like this:

```py
## create dummy input/output matrices
XData = tf.ones((1000, 20)) ## 1000 samples, 20 features
YData = tf.ones((1000, 50)) ## 1000 samples, 50 outputs
filterData = tf.ones((10, 50))
TrData = tf.ones((10, 50), dtype=tf.float32) ## 10 feature filters, 50 outputs

## input of size (n, 20)
input = keras.Input(XData.shape[1])
## dot product with filterData, out size = (n, 20, 10, 50)
tdot = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.tensordot(x, filterData, axes=0))(input)
## My modification
## change the order of dimensions in order to use the TimeDistributed layer
tdot_ = tf.transpose(tdot, [0, 3, 1, 2])
## This layer would try to train its parameters according to each output
tdense_ = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(XData.shape[1] * TrData.shape[0]),
                                                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)]))(tdot_)
## I used the Flatten to squeeze the output and the final shape would be (Batch, 50)
final_output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(tdense_)
```

But if it is not, then why you're not putting another Dense layer with a size of 50 after the `tdense`? like this:

```py
tdense = keras.layers.Dense(XData.shape[1] * TrData.shape[0], activation="linear")(tflat)
final_output = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="linear")(tdense)
```

**Update**

To address the issue you mentioned about the `For` loop, I did some modifications:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

## create dummy input/output matrices
XData = tf.ones((1000, 20)) ## 1000 samples, 20 features
YData = tf.ones((1000, 50)) ## 1000 samples, 50 outputs
filterData = tf.ones((10, 50))
TrData = tf.ones((10, 50), dtype=tf.float32) ## 10 feature filters, 50 outputs

## input of size (n, 20)
input = keras.Input(XData.shape[1])
## dot product with filterData, out size = (n, 20, 10, 50)
tdot = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.tensordot(x, filterData, axes=0))(input)
## My modification
## change the order of dimension in order to use TimeDistributed
tdot_ = tf.transpose(tdot, [0, 3, 1, 2])
## This layer would try to train its parameters according to each parameter
tdense_ = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())(tdot_)
tdense_ = [tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))(tdense_[:, :, i][..., None]) for i in range(XData.shape[1] * filterData.shape[0])]
tdense_ = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate())(tdense_)

## reduce dimensions through averaging to fit YData, out size = (n, 50)
tmean = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.reduce_mean(x, axis=(2)))(tdense_)
```

Comment: Thanks, the time distributed layer might be what I was looking for! Could you have a look at the EDIT I made above and help me implement the suggestion? I'd like to use your time distributed layer but without the dense layer of size 200 inside, and rather a collection of 200 single unit layers that each connect to a unique index of the prior layer. However this seems too complex for the sequential API and I'm struggling implementing it differently. Many thanks !

Comment: Hi @SoheilStar! Thanks for your help! I had to modified the third time distributed  line of your proposition to get it work, see edit 2 above. I had come up with a solution myself and they both seems to be equivalently poor. If you have suggestion on improving that learning aspect, I'll be glad to read them. In the mean time, thankx again and have a cookie :)
cheers

Comment: Hi @YoB. for that, I need to know about the data you have and also to know what is the project about.